# Statistical average MySQL / PHP

Tags: php, mysql, statistics

I have an application where students are making assignments. For each assignment / student, a result record is recorded. In this record, the score and the elapsed time is saved. Now I need to have a statistical average of the elapsed time per assignment as well as the score.

Unlike a normal average, this calculations needs to take the extremes into account (e.g. a student is idle for a while, which has a very high elapsed time as a result, I have to prevent that this value influences the average).

My question; what is the accepted approach for this problem? Are there any MySQL build in functions that are suitable for this case?

Comment: Excluding extremes is not a good idea. It looses the point of averaging... There are different approaches to get practical average....  Mean , median mode. More the results are closer the average is for all these approaches.

Comment: This is not really a database problem.  This is a data interpretation problem.  Did the student take a break between questions or did the student go do some research and then return to fill out the answer?  
Timestamps on database records alone will not tell you this.  If this were a test or an exam in a controlled environment, the averages might be meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is to use the median instead of the mean. It is far less sensitive to outliers.